# Is there a solid state switch for DC circuits?

Tags: power-supply, transistors, switches

I am working on a noobie IoT project and I am stuck. Please help!

I bought an ESP32 microcontroller and I want to use it to activate a garage remote for a couple of seconds upon an HTTP request.

The (really old) garage remote operates on a 9V battery and is activated via a button that is a piece of elastic metal that when pressed makes contact with two terminals, thus allowing electricity to pass through it.

I wonder if I can use a solid state switch to activate the remote by issuing a [`digitalWrite`](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/digital-io/digitalwrite/) with `HIGH` on a GPIO port of my ESP32. I thought this would be a use case of transistors, but I cannot get the setup to work; I tried connecting one of the terminals to the collector pin of a transistor and the other terminal to the emitter pin of that transistor; I then connected the base of the transistor to one of the GPIO ports and set it to `HIGH` and `LOW` to no avail.

I roughly know/believe that the culprit of the malfunction is that the ESP32 is operating with a separate power supply (a USB-wall power adapter) from the remote one (the 9V battery). Consequently, the transistor cannot work with different ground references, one in the collector/emitter and another one in the base.

How can I arrange my setup so that the transistor will understand the GPIO's changes and allow the remote's current to flow or not?

PS. If you can give me extra literature to understand your solution and deepen my knowledge on this, I would appreciate tremendously.

Comment: A common solution is to use an optocoupler or small relay. No need for common 0V between the two devices.

Comment: As the transistor can only work in one direction, passing current from higher voltage to lower voltage, are you sure you used the right kind of transistor (NPN vs PNP) and connected it the correct way (e.g. NPN would have more positive switch terminal on collector and more negative on emitter)? Also which kind of base resistor you used, because if you did not use any, the transistor or ESP32 can be damaged.

Comment: What’s keeping you from connecting the grounds of your 9V battery circuit and the ESP32? Or indeed an optocoupler might work as well if you don’t want to connect the grounds.

Comment: You can most likely do with a transistor but you *will* need to study the circuit of the remote to understand the right kind of transistor and how to use it. For "noob applications" I would have recommended a relay, which can directly replace a button without needing any understanding of the remote circuit, but it is not solid-state. Kartman's optocoupler idea might be better

Answer (score 6):

One of the possibility is to use a photovoltaic array to drive a gate of the MOSFET(s). Back to back MOSFET combination will work as relay - bidirectional.

You have to properly size an input resistor, similarly as you would use an optocoupler.

[image]

All in one IC if 120mA AC current or 250mA DC current is enough.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I suggest making/buying a dry contact module. It's a plain relay with both contacts exposed so that you can wire it up with any voltage you like. If you want, you can use an optocoupler to isolate the relay from ESP. Personally, I have found that N-mosfet works just fine. Make sure you are adding a free-wheeling diode to protect the mosfet.

Your circuit block will be:

ESP --- Mosfet --- Relay (with both contacts exposed)

Now you can disassemble your remote, solder two wires on the two contacts that get connected when you press the button. These two wires are connected to the relay contacts. In order to operate the garage door, you turn the relay ON for approx 200 ms and then turn it OFF. Depending upon exact relay you choose, you will have to figure some stuff out on your own. Some relays have three contacts (one is NC and one is NO, you can just ignore the NC contact)